# How i can disable multiple components Unity 3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

How i can disable multiple components of gameobject?

```
public void SaveComponents(GameObject obj, out List<Package> lista)
{
    print("SAVE");
    //Pobieramy wszystkie komponenty z obiektu
    Component[] components = obj.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
}
```

that example

```
components[1].enable = false;
```

not working for me, 'enable' it is not available :/

Answer (score 2):

It's because [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) doesn't have field called `enable`. This field is available within [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which is a parent class of [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

So if you want to disable all components you have to just disable the parent `GameObject` but if you want to disable components of your own data types just use :

```
public void SaveComponents(GameObject obj, out List<Package> lista)
{
    print("SAVE");
    //Pobieramy wszystkie komponenty z obiektu
    foreach(Behaviour behaviour in obj.GetComponents<Behaviour>()){
        behaviour.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

*"Component[] components = obj.GetComponents(typeof(Component)); <--- This is my array and I want to disable the selected elements of my array"* :

```
// list of all components without enable field in it
Component[] components = obj.GetComponents(typeof(Component));

int indexOfComponentToChange = 1; // index of the component to disable

Behaviour castedToBehaviour = components[indexOfComponentToChange] as Behaviour;
if ( castedToBehaviour != null )
{
    castedToBehaviour.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. There's no need to manually enter the class. Using above snippet result with disabling every "script" attached to the `GameObejct`.

Comment: Op was probably having problems with the GetComponents. I put obj in front of it....obj.GetComponents

Comment: I do not want to turn off all the elements, I want to turn off selected components ;)

Comment: Then do `behaviour[1].enable = false;`. What's hard about this?

Comment: Component[] components = obj.GetComponents(typeof(Component)); <--- This is my array and I want to disable the selected elements of my array